# Is strip_tags necessary for phpmailer?

Tags: phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer with the following settings:

```
$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
...
$mail->Body = $_POST['comments'];
$mail->Body = strip_tags($mail->Body);
```

I noticed strip_tags() cuts off the text if it hits a single greater than / less than sign (i.e if the user put in one of those characters legitimately).

Given that I have content type = 'text/plain' and ishtml = false, is it even necessary to have strip_tags() in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not neccesary. If you set `$mail->isHTML(false)` and you write HTML in the email, it is sent like text plain so it doesnt interpret it like HTML.

For example I've just done this:

```
$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain';
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->Subject = 'Your password';
$mail->Body = '<p>Your password is 123</p> <a href="www.google.com"> Go to google </a>';
```

And the mail looks like this:

```
<p>Your password is 123</p> <a href="wwww.google.com"> Go to google</a>
```

Comment: Goos answer. You don't need to set `ContentType` - calling `isHTML(false)` does that for you.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought.  Just wanted to verify.

Comment: @user1480951 Please, if you dont mind, mark this question as the correct one. Thank you.